# how to find which user executed the job

Tags: jenkins

We have LDAP login setup for user login and execute jobs. how to monitor users activities for the jobs that a particular user executed.

So far the only way I have seen is to go each job's console output and look for "Started by user". Is there any other way I can list all users with the jobs they executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin,
and adopt your build configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already looked at this plugin, it only helps to set variables. I am looking a way to get it display in the Build history